# SQL command line

Tags: java, mysql

my friend wants from me to write two queries for him but really I don't know ,would you please help me?
also there is a table with two column (String Telephone and BIGIN Charge).
the sentences that I want to write a query for that:

one: Reduce the “Charge” for all Telephone numbers starting with ‘123’ by 30.
two: Update all the Telephone numbers in the table by adding a ‘02’ in front of it.

thanks.

** I use MySQL**

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you sure this isn't just homework?

Comment: No really  this is not my homework.

Comment: my friend had found this questions also there are a lot except from these that we have done them by ourselves but we don't know what should we do for these  two lines!!

Comment: While posting the homework questions, please at least refrain from using exclamation marks in the title.

Comment: You should always remember to state which dbms you are using.

Comment: So is it your "friend"s homework?

Comment: i don't know!!!!!(I didn't ask from him!)

Comment: I just told him that i know a site that can help us and he wanted from me to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
 select charge - 30 from YourTable where Telephone like '123%'
```

or

```
 update YourTable set charge = charge - 30 where Telephone like '123%'
```

I'm in doubt whether reduce means update or select so I have added both.

```
 update YourTable set Telephone = '02' + Telephone
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String query;
        query = "update customer_info set Telephone = '02' + Telephone";






        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: @Johanna, always remember to `commit` after any change to your database.

Answer (score 1):

You get the null pointer exception because `stmt` is null. Typically, you have to create `stmt` by using `conn.createStatement()`. conn is the `java.sql.Connection` object.